# How to deploy printer with Profile Manager

Tags: osx-server, server.app, profile-manager, configuration-profiles, serveradmin

Good evening,
someone know the best practice for deploy printer on a mac with Profile Manager?

I have add to my Server on System->Printer the printer with AirPrint and it is recognised, with model and position.
I use payload "Print", but the printer is deployed on mac only with "generic driver".

I have tried to install first the driver and after push the payload, but doesn't work. Always "generic driver".

The problem is, generic driver some function are unavailable... Some ideas?

Thanks